# Remove unwanted hyphen from variable

Tags: r

I have data as below

```
0-0098-45.3A-22
0-0104-44.0A-23
0-0983-29.1-22
0-1757-42.5A-22
0-4968-37.3A2-23
000000-44.0a-23
000000-45.3A-42
```

is there any way to remove initial unwanted hypen and make it like below in R

```
00098-45.3A-22
00104-44.0A-23
00983-29.1-22
01757-42.5A-22
04968-37.3A2-23
000000-44.0a-23
000000-45.3A-42
```

Any help would be much helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sub` to remove the unwanted `-` at 2nd position of the string.  We use `^` to specify the start of the string, capture the first character as a group (`(.)` - `.` is a metacharacter which refers to any character element) followed by `-` and in the replacement we use the backreference (`\\1`) for that captured group.

```
df$v1 <- sub('^(.)-', '\\1', df$v1)
df$v1
#[1] "00098-45.3A-22"  "00104-44.0A-23"  "00983-29.1-22"   
#[4] "01757-42.5A-22"  "04968-37.3A2-23" "000000-44.0a-23" "000000-45.3A-42"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(v1 = c("0-0098-45.3A-22", "0-0104-44.0A-23", "0-0983-29.1-22", 
"0-1757-42.5A-22", "0-4968-37.3A2-23", "000000-44.0a-23", "000000-45.3A-42"
)), .Names = "v1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```